# External binding file with Add Web Reference

Tags: .net, web-services

I am consuming a external service using Add Web Reference in .NET 2010. It is giving me some error as below..

```
---------------------------
Microsoft Visual Studio
---------------------------
The custom tool 'MSDiscoCodeGenerator' failed.  Schema with
targetNamespace='http://www.isotc211.org/2005/gmd' has invalid syntax.
The complexType 'http://www.isotc211.org/2005/gmd:MD_Metadata_Type' has
already been declared. Line 15, position 4.
---------------------------
OK   
---------------------------
```

Is there an option to override the `.xsd` file which causes above issue?

Comment: Take a look at your App_WebReferences folder, you will find a file with .wsdl extension. You can just change it or update web references (right click on App_WebReferences folder on Visual Studio).

Comment: There is nothing i can change in .wsdl extension file. Seems like certain schema refernced by this web service has some duplicate Property Entry. I just checked with the web service provider they had given me ".xjb" file and this file fix this issue for Java developers.